# Python - How to create a JSON nested file from a Pandas dataframe and group by?

Tags: python, json, pandas

so I'm having some troubles to create an appropriate JSON format from a pandas dataframe. My dataframe looks like this (sorry for the csv format):

```
first_date, second_date, id, type, codename, description, price
201901,201902,05555,111,01111,1,200.00
201901,201902,05555,111,023111,44,120.00
201901,201902,05555,111,14113,23,84.00
```

As you can see, the first four rows have repeated values, so I would like to group all my columns in two groups to get this JSON file:

```
[
    {
     "report": 
           {
              "first_date":201901,
              "second_date": 201902,
              "id":05555,
              "type": 111   
            },
     "features": [
           {
              "codename":01111,
              "description": 1,
              "price":200.00
            },
           {
              "codename":023111,
              "description": 44,
              "price":120.00
            },
           {
              "codename":14113,
              "description": 23,
              "price":84.00
            }

       ]
    }
 ]
```

So far I've tried to group by the last three columns, add them to a dictionary and rename them:

```
cols = ["codename","description","price"]
rep = (df.groupby(["first_date","second_date","id","type"])[cols]
       .apply(lambda x:x.to_dict('r')
       .reset_index(name="features")
       .to_json(orient="records"))
output = json.dumps(json.loads(rep),indent=4)
```

And I get this as the output:

```
[
    {
      "first_date":201901,
      "second_date": 201902,
      "id":05555,
      "type": 111,

      "features": [
           {
              "codename":01111,
              "description": 1,
              "price":200.00
            },
           {
              "codename":023111,
              "description": 44,
              "price":120.00
            },
           {
              "codename":14113,
              "description": 23,
              "price":84.00
            }

       ]
    }
 ]
```

Can anyone guide me to rename and group the first group of columns? Or does anyone knows another approach to this problem? I would like to do it this way since I have to repeat the same procedure but with more groups of columns and searching, this seems simpler than to create the son from several for loops.

Any advice sure will be helpful! I've been searching a lot but this is my first approach to this type of output. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you :

```
#get rid of whitespaces if any
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
#split into two sections
fixed = df.columns[:4]
varying = df.columns[4:]
#create dicts for both fixed and varying 
features = df[varying].to_dict('records')
report = df[fixed].drop_duplicates().to_dict('records')[0]
#combine into a dict into a list : 
fin = [{"report":report,"features":features}]
print(fin)
[{'report': {'first_date': 201901,
             'second_date': 201902,
             'id': 5555,
             'type': 111},
 'features': [{'codename': 1111, 'description': 1, 'price': 200.0},
              {'codename': 23111, 'description': 44, 'price': 120.0},
              {'codename': 14113, 'description': 23, 'price': 84.0}]}]
```